# How to select the version of postgresql version among two different version in ubuntu?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ubuntu, postgis, psql

I have two installation of postgreSQL i.e postgres v12(in port 5433) and postgres v13(in port 5432) in the system. But when i type psql in commandline, only the version 13 runs. How can I go with selecting the postgres v12?

Comment: In Debian/Ubuntu packaging the latest version of `psql` is used as it is backwards compatible. Other commands can be made version specific by using the `--cluster` option. For all the details see `man postgresql-common`.